# Links from echo statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering how to make my php echo statements into links. I'd like the user to be able to hover over the table row once it has been filled with info from mysql and respond by displaying an image.

```
 <?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row["type"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row["price"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo $row["available"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: <?php echo "<a href='yourlink'>$row[type]</a>"; ?>

Comment: So what you are really asking is how to display an image when you hover over a row. So what is the image you want to display? Where do you want to  display it where and where does it come from? There is no references to images in your supplied code.

Answer (score 0):

Good evening lom17,

Have you already tried the basic echo statement? See below.

```
<?php

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo "<a href='#'>" . $row["name"] . "</a>"; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo "<a href='#'>" . $row["type"] . "</a>"; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo "<a href='#'>" . $row["price"] . "</a>"; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo "<a href='#'>" . $row["available"] . "</a>"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Of course, if you're wanting to go this route, it might be best to just keep everything within PHP. See my other example below.

```
<?php
    While ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          Echo "    <tr>
                    <td><a href='#'>" . $row["name"] . "</a></td>
                    <td align='center'><a href='#'>" . $row["type"] . "</a></td>
                    <td align='center'><a href='#'>" . $row["price"] . "</a></td>
                    <td align='center'><a href='#'>" . $row["available"] . "</a></td>
                </tr>";
    }
?>
```

This solution would be much cleaner and should accomplish what you're trying to do. I hope this helps! If not, comment below and we can figure something out!

Regards,

Tim

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do something like the following.

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "
    <tr onclick=\"window.location.replace='http://example.com';\" style='cursor:pointer;'>
        <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
        <td align='center'>".$row["type"]."</td>
        <td align='center'>".$row["price"]."</td>
        <td align='center'>".$row["available"]."</td>
    </tr>";
}
?>
```

You can also, echo an `<a>` element into each of the `<td>`, but using javascript as in my example cuts down on repetitive code / typing.